# How to cut file name not actual file

Tags: cut

I have a list of file names like

> ./run_results/rat/coding_exons/0.01_100_best.txt
>   ./run_results/mouse/introns/0.01_100_best.txt

I want to create new files with names like `rat_coding_exons_0.01_100_best.txt` or `mouse_introns_0.01_100_best.txt`

Problem is, when I try to cut these file names, cut instead starts cutting each line in said files (sensible, but not what I want).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure by what method you're passing those filenames to `cut`, but it seems that you're passing them as filenames rather than data to manipulate.

```
cut ... << 'EOF'
file1
file2
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `cut filename` you want `echo filename | cut` (i.e. pass the filenames to cut as the input from stdin).

Comment: Works by itself, but when I pipe commands from find to echo it does not work. `find . -name "*0.01*txt" | echo ` returns nothing so there is nothing for me to cut. That, however is not your fault so upvote.

Comment: It was an example, the difference between giving cut the filename to process and giving cut a string which matches the filename to process.